# Select attribute values into a list

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following xml:

```
<ListOfItems>
   <item myval='123' />
   <item myval='342' />
   <item myval='233' />
   <item myval='444' />
</ListOfItems>
```

I'm parsing/traversing it with jQuery.  What is a selector that would give me a list of all values in the attribute 'myval' of 'item' nodes.  I'm looking for something that would give me  back a list of values only. Maybe an array [ '123, '342', '233', '444' ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bearing in mind that I don't think those are valid elements, I'd suggest:

```
var listOfValues = [];

$('ListOfItems > item').each(
    function(){
        listOfValues.push($(this).attr('myval'));
    });
```

Given the desire to use a single selector, the following is possible:

```
var myvals = $('li').map(
    function(){
        return this.getAttribute('myval');
    }).get().join(', ');
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Sh4Yt/).

Comment: I was curious if I can do this with some kind of selector.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to iterate through the list of items.  For example:

```
var itemsArray = [];
$("ListOfItems").each(function(index) {
    itemsArray[index] = $(this).attr('myval');
});
```

Comment: just fyi, $(#ListItems") will give me top node but not its 'item' children. $("item") or $("#ListItems > item") would work. but overall the suggested way will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = new Array();
$(xml).find('item').each(function() {
   data.push($(this).attr('myval'));
});
```

where `xml` is your xml content.

or:

```
var array = $(xml).find('item').map(function() {
       return $(this).attr('myval');
    }).get();
```

Comment: I was curious if I can do this with some kind of selector.

Comment: As I know you can't because jQuery selectors can take only elements

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function.

```
var listOfItems = $('ListOfItems items').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('myval');
});
```

It's a really nifty function (along with `$.map()`) that a lot of people miss out on.

Just keep in mind that that returns a jQuery object, so if you want to get your hands on the *raw* returned array, you'll have to get to it via `listOfItems.get()`.